# VMWare - Virtual operating system static IP address

Tags: vmware, virtualization, nat, dhcp, static-ip-address

What is the best way to have a virtual operating system have a static IP address in VMWware. I would like to keep the IP address static since it is a virtual server.

Comment: I think it should be moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you're not using NAT-based VMWare networking, the answer isn't any different for a virtual (guest) server than for a real one. You can:

- Assign a static IP via whatever mechanism the guest operating system supports.
- Configure the guest operating system to get its IP address from a DHCP server, and configure the DHCP server to return a static IP address for the VMWare instance's MAC address.

Answer (score 22):

You can configure VMware DHCP server [which runs on host OS] to assign a fix IP address to a VM each time.

According to [vmware docs](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-04D783E1-3AB9-4D98-9891-2C58215905CC.html), configuration is stored at the following locations:

Windows XP

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf`

Windows Vista or Windows 7

`C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf`

Linux (host-only)

`/etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcp/dhcp.conf`

Linux (NAT)

`/etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcp/dhcp.conf`

VMWare Fusion for Mac (host-only)

`/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet1/dhcpd.conf`

VMWare Fusion for Mac (NAT)

`/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf`

Static IP and DNS name by MAC example:

```
host ubuntu {
    hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:c0:2c:58;
    fixed-address 192.168.118.3;
}
```

For more details on this please see this [blog post](http://codefry.blogspot.com/2013/04/assigning-fix-ip-address-to-vmware-vm.html).

Comment: Worked great for me. Incase you vmx file has spaces in the name like: "Documents\Virtual Machines\CentOS 7 64-bit\CentOS 7 64-bit.vmx" you should use `host 'CentOS 7 64-bit' {`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the VM slice / VM machine (guest) to have a static IP, assign it to the VM slice.  Then on the VM Server select "Bridged" for the network adapter settings.  This tells VMWare to use what ever IP settings you have established on the guest.

Answer (score 3):

**This works on my machine**

Follow these simple steps. Takes just 5 minutes.

```
1. Note the MAC of the VM
2. On the host machine open C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf
    a. Or C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf 
    b. These 2 files are auto synced or mirrored. 
    c. Open the editor in Administrator mode. Eg notepad++. Otherwise you will get access denied message
3. Add a new entry at bottom of the configuration file, right before the "# End" marker. MyGuestVM is any unique name. Example below

host sunilW2008Server {
hardware ethernet 00-0C-29-05-2B-A0;
fixed-address 192.168.63.222;
}

3. Shutdown the VM and close the Workstation
4. Re-start the VMWare DHCP and NAT services for changes to take effect (From services.msc)
```

Notes:
the below folders are at sync automatically.. change at one place and the same will be reflected on the other folder

C:\ProgramData\VMware
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround, configure the *vmware dhcp server* to use longer leases.
In the *vmware* config folder (on *windows 7* -- `C:\ProgramData\vmware`) edit the file
*vmnetdhcp.conf* and change the values of `default-lease-time` and `max-lease-time` to
something bigger say 4 months (`4mo*30days*24hours*60min*60sec = 10368000`).
Then restart the *vmware dhcp server*.  Then release and renew the lease on the guest.
Now your guest *IP* is *static* for next four months.

Comment: No--this is not a static IP and I this is just bad advice. "Static IP" means that the IP will never change--not that it changes after a long time. Most reasons for using a static IP require the IP address to map to a particular machine on a network and sometimes those IP references are hardcoded into shortcuts, batch jobs, etc. Your strategy would wreak havoc should the lease expire.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to leave the VM host configuration as default, it is also possible to configure the guest machine to request a fixed address for dhcp. This will work even for the NAT network. In the case of Ubuntu and `dhclient`, this is achieved by the following block in `dhclient.conf`:

```
interface "eth0" {
    send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.1.222;
}
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/381137